# Accepting lists as URL params with Colander

Tags: python, colander

I'm trying to accept a URL-serialized version of the following Python `dict` using Colander as my validation backend:

```
{'foo': [1,2,3]}
```

The way I've approached this was primarily using `colander.SequenceSchema` in various configurations, none of which produce errors that make much sense:

```
# first approach
class ListItem(colander.MappingSchema):
    item = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int())

class ListContainer(colander.SequenceSchema):
    items = ListItem()
```

---

```
# second approach
class ListContainer(colander.SequenceSchema):
    items = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int())
```

---

```
# third approach
colander.SchemaNode(
    colander.Mapping(),
    colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.Sequence(),
        typ=colander.Int(),
        name=my_param_name
    )
)
```

---

I'm actually fairly sure the first two approaches are equivalent.

In terms of actually validating this, I've tried using a number of structures passed to the `params` kwarg on a `requests.get` call:

- `my_param_name = [1,2,3]`
- `my_param_name = [(my_param_name, 1), (my_param_name, 2), (my_param_name, 3)]`
- `my_param_name = {my_param_name: [1,2,3]}`

In every case, Colander will spit out some variation upon `my_param_name: u'"1" is not iterable'`, or in the last case, `my_param_name: u'"[1,2,3]" is not iterable'`. This error is very obtuse, and [the docs](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html?highlight=list#colander.Sequence) don't outline a correct use case for `SequenceSchema` (or even `colander.List`) for accepting arrays as values in a URL parameter, and because of Colander's relatively low adoption, it's difficult to find a project on the web which uses either of these in this way.

Is it possible to accept a list of scalar, primitive values as the value of a URL parameter while passing validation using Colander?